# can we request a particular div in python

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to access a website's particular div,
can I access it?
if we can pls share an example.
**I have watched many videos on this but all videos are for tables only(mostly)**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, using beautiful soup.

For example, you can refine your search to only find those divs with a given class:

```
mydivs = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "class_to_find"})
```

Take a look here :
https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Use Beautiful Soup, a python library which can work with HTML/XML files.

1. `soup.find('div', class_='your_div_class')`
2. `soup.select('div.your_class_name')[0]`